# I don't clearly see why this is the Fibonacci sequence. Am I intelligent enough to be a Haskell programmer?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fibonacci

This is a way to get the Fibonacci sequence in Haskell. It's from the book haskellbook.com (supposedly for beginners):

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
```

I can only "see" that this is Fibonacci after writing out a few of the first elements manually:

```
1 : scanl (+) 1 (1 : scanl (+) 1 (1 : scanl (+) 1 (1 : 1 ...
1 : scanl (+) 1 (1 : scanl (+) 1 (1 : 1 : 2 : 3 ...
1 : scanl (+) 1 (1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 ...
1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 : 13 : 21 ...
```

Only now do I have some intuition into why this is the Fibonacci sequence. But I had to write it out like this first. And even then it's still just an intuition, not solid proof.

I have three questions:

1. Was I supposed to immediately just spot the Fibonacci sequence from the original line?
2. Would some of you professional Haskell programmer in here of 5-10 years, if you had for the sake of argument never before seen this particular example, immediately have seen that the original line is the Fibonacci sequence?
3. I sometimes find myself wondering whether I'm intelligent enough to be a Haskell programmer. Maybe it's just not for me. Haskell makes me feel inadequate sometimes :( Never had this feeling with other programming languages. So the third question: Have any tests/methods been developed to determine whether a particular programmer is intelligent enough to be a Haskell programmer? (I'm pretty sure Haskell requires a higher IQ than most other languages!)

Comment: "Am I intelligent enough for X" is not a programming question. Sorry. (Voting to close). However I can tell you that creative currying is a mental skill you get better at, just like enumerating for loops is something you learn how to do automatically when you work with C, but really isn't that easy for beginners.

Comment: from the `What topics can I ask about here?` section on stackoverflow I couldn't find a reason why this is not a relevant question. It obviously relates to programming, even though the question is opinion based. How is "Am I intelligent enough for X" not a programming question, if X is replaced by a programming language? You can't just strip the relevant part from a question and then claim it is off topic!

Comment: If this were phrased like "why does this produce the fibonacci sequence" or "how am I supposed to understand what this does", that would be a reasonable question. "Am I a smart person?" is just not a question anyone here can possibly answer, and it's not on topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the asker's mental capacity, instead of about haskell.

Comment: Most of intelligence is just familiarity.  You worked it out yourself, which is more than a lot of people do.  Keep doing that and you'll be a pro.  (I would like to share, at the time I started learning Haskell I had just picked up Ruby in 2 days, so the 6 months it took to get comfortable in Haskell was, let's say, disheartening.  I think that's just the nature of the beast though.  It's more akin to relearning programming than learning a new language.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Haskell's fibonacci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404156/understanding-haskells-fibonacci)

Comment: I had to look up `scanl` and see that `scanl f x (y : ys) = x : scanl (f x y) ys`. That definition is the key, and I certainly didn't remember it. But then I could see that `fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs` gives me `fibs = 1 : gibs` where `gibs = scanl (+) 1 (1 : gibs) = 1 : scanl (+) 2 gibs`. Which means `gibs = 1 : hibs` where `hibs = scanl (+) 2 (1 : hibs) = 2 : scanl (+) 3 hibs`. Before each step, we have two consecutive Fibonacci numbers: one before scanl, one waiting in the scanl. Each step slides the window: the "waiting" element emerges and is replaced in the scanl by the sum of the pair.

Comment: Joining the chorus here, but if you wrote it out by hand and figured it out, the answer is clearly yes, you are.

Comment: most important is to *name* all your interim entities as they come into play, like in the comment by pigworker (the `gibs` and the `hibs` i.e. `fibs2`, `fibs3`, ... ; etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Was I supposed to immediately just spot the Fibonacci sequence from the original line?

Heck no! You were supposed to read the example, scratch your head, write it out manually... and *thereby* get an intuition for how `scanl` works and why this can be used for Fibonacci numbers.

> Would some of you ... have seen that the original line is the Fibonacci sequence?

Well, it *is* called `fibs`... apart from that, yeah, `scanl` is standard enough that an experienced programmer would quickly see what's going on.

> pretty sure Haskell requires a higher IQ

I think Haskell requires most of all a good deal of *stubbornness*, and a particular sense of æsthetics. Haskell has some quirky ways of doing stuff different. Some of these are a bit hard to grasp, but most of all they're just *unfamiliar* to most programmers. It's all about getting used to the stuff.

And because, if we're honest, Haskell skills are still not a terribly utilitarian thing right now (as in, any real-world task can be solved as well by some other language too), you really need some enthusiasm for the language's beauty and future potential to keep up with it.

Note that Haskell's quirks and features have a tendency to slowly seep into mainstream languages. So, even if “Haskell is not for you” you may in the long term benefit from the nice things that are prototyped here, perhaps without even noticing where they come from.

Answer (score 4):

1. Like any other language, the semantics of code should - to some extend - document itself, so the answer is yes. But at the same time it takes time getting used to the syntax - just like with any other language. Don't worry, you'll get it. Just try not to back away from such problems and embrace them. Working them through step by step is a good approach, keep doing that!
2. I am neither a professional Haskell programmer, nor did I learn it 10 years ago, but to some extend yes. Just like you don't *understand* the Fibonacci in any other language within half a second when you see it, I'd have to think about it, but I'd get it a **lot** fast compared to the time I started writing in Haskell.
3. Like any other programming language, Haskell takes a certain mindset to be read and understood easily and quickly. Just remember the first time you saw code in any other language. Chances are, you felt the exact same thing, but don't remember it as vividly. As Haskell is a very maths inspired language, many non-mathematicians often struggle with the notation and the style of coding.
   My advise is not give up. You probably didn't have 3 years worth of maths at university, so it will just take a little while.
   But there is a huge pot of gold at the end of this rainbow. From my experience people who wrote Haskell code understand functional programming on a level no one else ever could! It will certainly help writing elegant code in any other language!